# Is android:drawableStart in androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton supported by android 4.4?

Tags: android-button, androidx, android-4.4-kitkat

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/Black"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonFoo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_foo_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/foo" />
/androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

The above activity layout would cause the following exception on Android 4.4 when the activity starts:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #123: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

It happens only on Android 4.4.  All other devices are fine.
Everything will be fine if the following is removed:

```
android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_foo_icon"
```

Is android:drawableStart in androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton supported by android 4.4?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use drawableLeft / drawableRight instead?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help.  drawableLeft / drawableRight has the same problem.